# Mock testing examples for mongo-async-driver and mockito

Tags: mongodb, mockito, mongodb-asyc-driver

I am learning mongo, and have found examples for standard mongo. What im trying to do is mock using async driver but have had no luck.

Any documentation or sites with examples, anyone know of?

regards

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/